# Finding the radius of convergence of a series with only even powers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n}}{(2+i)^n}$, and I need to find its radius of convergence.

I cannot think how to arrange this so I can find $ R= \lim |\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}|$. I tried relabelling the series with $m=2n$, and went with it which produced the correct answer, though I then realised that the 'relabelled' series will contain terms not in my original series! The relabelling seemed to disguise the problem, rather than remove it, yet obtained the right answer anyway.

My question is whether this *was* the correct way to proceed, but for reasons I am unaware of, or if not how I should approach this problem.

Comment: Try the root test.

Comment: Essentially, what you've done is to reinterpret your power series as a composition between $z\mapsto z^2$ and a power series with coefficients $b_n = 1/(2+i)^n$. That is a valid approach to the problem.

Comment: @Braindead Could you explain in more detail please? I don't really understand. Also the coefficients became $b_m = 1/(2+i)^{m/2}$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of your power series as a composition of two functions, $g\circ h$, where

$h(z) = z^2$, and $g(w) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{w^n}{(2+i)^n}$.

If you apply the ratio test on $g$, you would compute the following limit:

$R' = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\dfrac{1/(2+i)^{n}}{1/(2+i)^{n+1}}\right| = |2+i|=\sqrt{5}$

But this is the radius of convergence for $g$, i.e. for $w$. To get the radius for $z$, you'd do

$|z^2| < \sqrt{5}$, which turns into $|z| < \sqrt[4]{5} = R$

Now, what you've essentially done is to do what I did in two steps in a single step:

$R = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\dfrac{1/(2+i)^{n/2}}{1/(2+i)^{(n+1)/2}}\right|=\sqrt{\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\dfrac{1/(2+i)^{n}}{1/(2+i)^{n+1}}\right|} = \sqrt[4]{5}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, wonderfully clear! :)